# Sudden appearence of debug/AndroidManifest, execution failed for task:app:processDebugResources

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

I recently connected my mobile device up to android studio in order to attempt a build on a real device, before this, everything was working fine. However, the debug manifest is now showing some strange issues.

For example, the android version code and version name is coming up red, as are the config changes and the theme.

The actual error is:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\bembe_000\AppData\Local\Android\sdk1\build-tools\23.0.0\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1